# How does Big Query differentiate between a day and month when we upload any CSV or text file?

Tags: sql, csv, date, google-bigquery, schema

I have a local csv file having table name as `market_date_info`. One of the column in this table is `market_date`. The date is in DD-MM-YYYY format. Below are first 5 rows of the column shown in attached picture. I have taken only 5 rows just for the sake of simplicity.
[First_5_rows_of_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZB1C.png)

I uploaded this csv file table on google Big Query by selecting `schema Auto Detect`. It changed the date format to default YYYY-MM-DD. The uploaded table is shown in the following attached picture. [Table_in_bigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8rlE.jpg)
Everything is Okay. The table got uploaded as expected. But I have following query:

`How does BigQuery decides that in the original csv file format i.e. DD-MM-YYYY which value is for date , and which value is for month?` Suppose there is a date 02-03-1999. Here in this `02` can represent a month also. How does bigquery know that `02` is day not a month?

Suppose in the csv or txt file, the date format is MM-DD-YYYY. For eg 3rd Feb,1999 is represented as 02-03-1999. Will Big query still be able to detect that `02` is for month and `03` is for date. Will Bigquery successfully convert it to YYYY-MM-DD format?

`What is the underlying process by which Bigquery decides that a value is a day or a month?`